# base64_encode function return null string when input large string

Tags: php, encryption, base64

i created a web service for sending files and that saved in server. The file format is zip. The file size may vary in the user need.

This is my code for before sending data in to server.

```
   $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/data.zip';

   $data = file_get_contents($filename);
   $new_data = base64_encode($data);
```

This new_data variable send to the server.
This worked in all small files. But base64_encode return null when i use 5 mb file or larger file.

my problem is that base64_encode is not working in large string i genrated.

if any one know about this please help me.

Comment: Turn on error reporting - `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. My guess is that you're exhausting your post max and the memory allocated.

Comment: There is no error present.But response generated when i used var_dumb($new_data)..

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: `file_get_contents()` is returning `false` which, when passed to `base64_encode()`, results in an [empty string](https://3v4l.org/dPEEA).

Why is `file_get_contents()` failing? It could be any number of reasons:

- You don't have read permissions on the file. `chmod()` may help, but it's likely  something caused elsewhere.
- Memory limits prevent `file_get_contents()` from loading 5 MB of text into memory.
- Filesystem or disk errors. (Unlikely but strictly possible.)